# Google App Engine Launcher cannot run application

Tags: python

After I lauch the Google App Engine Laucher, and add the "customtinywebdb" downloaded from web, but it can't run the application. It shows an exclamation mark beside the application. I already install Python 2.7.

In the log file:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
2014-05-03 18:40:53 (Process exited with code 1);
```

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue9291

Comment: possible duplicate of [exception when installing setuptools on python 2.7.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207914/exception-when-installing-setuptools-on-python-2-7-6)

Comment: The bug report [includes a patch](http://bugs.python.org/file34983/issue9291.8.patch).